# Minimum pull P through center which will turn the wheel over the block

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

[image: hello]

**My attempt**

For turning the wheel over the block, the force must pull its center to a position where it is vertically above the corner about which it climbs. In order to do so, gravity would do -ve work of 15 Joules. Assuming $\Delta {KE=0}$, the force P must do an equal amount of +ve work. (As work done by normals is zero)

If angle between force and  horizontal is $\theta$, the final equation I get is $$P\sin{(\frac{π}{3}+\theta)}=500 N$$ (*assuming P is constant*)
Now, if P is to be minimised, $\theta$ must be equal to $\frac{π}{6}$. This gives P=500N.

But I am supposed to get answer 500√3N, which one gets by balancing torque of weight of wheel and P about corner of block (As the normal reaction between wheel and surface is zero, the wheel would be lifted up).

But I don't understand what's wrong with my method. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't assume constant force. The most challenging state is the initial state, when the largest force is required (by torque considerations). Once lifted, less and less force is required.

The question specifically requires the minimal force. So you must calculate based on torques at the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mistake sin for cos?
The answer is correct.
If you want to choose analytical mechanics to solve this,you should realize that the direction of P cannot point to the right.
[image]